# How best to handle a common mis-spelling of my domain name?

Tags: htaccess, 404, error

My surname is Kirkby, but very often people mis-spell it, by leaving out the second 'k' and so spell it as Kirby.

My domain name is kirkbymicrowave.co.uk, but I took a guess that a few people at least would be searching for www.kirbymicrowave.co.uk. I'm wondering the best way to use this. So far I have

1. Added a simple index.html, which explains the problem. That has

   ```
   <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
   ```

   in the header.
2. Added a line to .htaccess

   ```
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
   ```

   so any file they search for that does not exist, will generate a 404 error, and give message they are on the wrong domain.

Have I done the best things? What should or should I not have done?

Comment: I mean the header has 'noindex, nofollow' as a meta tag for robots.

Comment: Have you considered a redirect?

Comment: To clarify, you have registered the misspelled domain and this _noindex_ `meta` tag and 404 error document are served from this domain? This will only catch users that specifically request the misspelled domain, not if they "search" for it - since it won't be indexed.